# How to get (name,type) from AttributeArgumentListSyntax in Roslyn C#

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want to get list of (name,type) from AttributeArgumentListSyntax

```
    public static List<Tuple<string, string>> GetArguments(this AttributeSyntax node)
    {
        var args = node.ArgumentList.Arguments.ToList();
        if (args.Count > 0)
        {
            var list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
            foreach (var arg in args)
            {
                var name = ""; // ??????????????
                var type = ""; // ??????????????
                list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(name, type));
            }
            return list;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Can anyone help me ?

Result like this :

```
[Obsolete("A",true)]
public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }


(A,string)
(true,bool)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the SemanticModel from your `Compilation` or `Project`.

Once you have that, you can call `GetSymbol()` to get the type of the value passed (which may not be the same as the type of the attribute's constructor parameter).